# How to inherit QtWidgets.QWidget in my class and make my class type - QtWidgets.QWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, maya

I am trying to make some code in Maya, I am sorry if it will cause any confuse in my script example below. 
Problem is that I want to make my custom PyQt class which will later used as Widget in my Layout, but my lack of knowledge in this thing , causing error

```
# RuntimeError: '__init__' method of object's base class (test) not called. #
```

I read few topics about that error and people suggest to fix it with super().
I tried to put "super()" , then I am getting this error :

```
# TypeError: PySide2.QtCore.QObject isn't a direct base class of test #
```

Can somebody clear this thing for me ?

```
from PySide2 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
from shiboken2 import wrapInstance
import maya.OpenMaya as om
import maya.OpenMayaUI as omui
import maya.cmds as cmds
import os, functools


def getMayaWindow():
    pointer = omui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    if pointer is not None:
        return wrapInstance(long(pointer), QtWidgets.QWidget)

class testUi():
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = 'vl_test'
        self.title = 'Test Remastered'
        self.size = (1000, 650)

    def create(self):
        if cmds.window(self.window, exists=True):
            cmds.deleteUI(self.window, window=True)

        self.parentWindow = getMayaWindow()
        self.mainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow(self.parentWindow)
        self.mainWindow.setObjectName(self.window)
        self.mainWindow.setWindowTitle(self.title)

        self.mainWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.mainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.mainWidget)
        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QFormLayout(self.mainWidget)
        testik = test(self)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(testik)

        self.mainButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.mainButton)
        self.mainButton.clicked.connect(partial(self.load_selected))


class test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, maya_transform_nodes=[]):
        #super(QtWidgets.QWidget, self ).__init__(parent)
        qWid = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setMinW = qWid.setMinimumWidth(300)
        self.setMinH = qWid.setMinimumHeight(300)
        self.sss = qWid.setStyleSheet("border:1px solid rgb(0, 255, 0); ")
        self.items = []

        self.transform_move = QtGui.QTransform()
        self.transform_scale = QtGui.QTransform()

        self.prev_mouse_pos = QtCore.QPoint(0, 0)

        self.color = QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 50, 50)
        self.clicked_color = QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 50, 150)
        self.right_clicked_color = QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0, 150)

v = testUi()
v.create()
```

Comment: Do `super(Test, self).__init__(parent)`, and use `self` instead of `qWid`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a class you have an option to inherit from another object, in this case probably a `QDialog` since it's your tool's main window. It's not enough to simply inherit it though, you have to call `QDialog`'s constructor in order for it to initialize properly, and you can do that with `super`.

With `super` you can choose to run a method from your class's object it inherited from. It will look something like this: `super(YOUR_CLASS_NAME, INSTANCE).METHOD_TO_RUN(PARAMETERS_TO_PASS)`. So more specifically to run your `__init__` it will be: `super(testUi, self).__init__(parent)`, and that will fix it.

That was probably an awful explanation so please Google `super` for much better examples.

I did some edits to your script to simplify it and left some comments in it:

```
from PySide2 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWidgets
from shiboken2 import wrapInstance
import maya.OpenMaya as om
import maya.OpenMayaUI as omui
import maya.cmds as cmds
import os, functools


def getMayaWindow():
    pointer = omui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    if pointer is not None:
        return wrapInstance(long(pointer), QtWidgets.QWidget)


class testUi(QtWidgets.QDialog):  # Need to inherit from a `QObject`

    def __init__(self, parent=None):  # It's typical to include the `parent` parameter and pass that through `super`.
        # If nothing was passed for parent, default to Maya's main window.
        if parent is None:
            parent = getMayaWindow()

        super(testUi, self).__init__(parent)  # Call `super` with the class's name, testUi, and its instance, self.
        self.window = 'vl_test'
        self.title = 'Test Remastered'
        self.size = (1000, 650)

        self.create()  # Just automatically call create in the instance's constructor.

    def create(self):
        if cmds.window(self.window, exists=True):
            cmds.deleteUI(self.window, window=True)

        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.resize(QtCore.QSize(*self.size))

        self.testik = test(self)  # Add `self.` so it belongs to this instance.

        self.mainButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton()

        self.mainLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()  # QVBoxLayout seems to give a better result.
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.testik)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.mainButton)
        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)  # Don't forget to make this widget actually set to this layout and use it.


class test(QtWidgets.QFrame):

    def __init__(self, parent=None, maya_transform_nodes=[]):
        super(test, self).__init__(parent)  # Call `super` with the class's name, test, and its instance, self.

        self.setMinimumWidth(300)
        self.setMinimumHeight(300)
        self.setStyleSheet("QWidget {border: 1px solid rgb(0, 255, 0)};")

        self.items = []

        self.transform_move = QtGui.QTransform()
        self.transform_scale = QtGui.QTransform()

        self.prev_mouse_pos = QtCore.QPoint(0, 0)

        self.color = QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 50, 50)
        self.clicked_color = QtGui.QColor(0, 255, 50, 150)
        self.right_clicked_color = QtGui.QColor(255, 0, 0, 150)


v = testUi()
v.show()  # Call show to show it!
```

Am I right to assume you're trying to build a synoptics? If yes, you might want to check out `QGraphicsView` to populate a window with items and to handle most of the logic. Otherwise you will have to do it 100% yourself, which could be lots of fun, but lots of extra work.

Comment: You are awesome, thanks for your work and comments in scripts. It was really helpful and I think I got how it works . Yes , I am trying build synoptics?!(didn't know that there is a word for that). I know that there is existing QGraphicsView, but wanted to try to build some widget myself. Thanks again.